# CKAN: Error 500

Tags: postgresql, solr, ckan

Trying to install CKAN on Ubuntu 14.04 and decided to follow this method: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html. Everything has installed correctly, except I get a 500 Error on the CKAN page when I open up my http://localhost.

I'm pretty sure it's related to the command:

```
sudo ckan db init
```

When I do that command, it says [Errno 111] Connection refused... Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server.

Additionally, if I take a look at my ckan_default.error.log file, this is what I get: [image]

What could I possibly be doing wrong? What file do I need to edit to fix this connection to the SOLR server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can't connect to the Solr server. I'd double check all steps in this section:

http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#setup-solr

Specially restarting Jetty once finished:

`sudo service jetty restart`

Comment: Thanks!! So it turns out I had the incorrect version number for my Java in the /etc/default/jetty file. So instead of this:
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/`

I needed this: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`